# Response body was dropped to conserve memory

Tags: fiddler

I have 16 GB memory, and why is fiddler drop body (doesn't parse the body) to conserve memory?

how to disable this feature?

[image: the options page]

[image: the note]

Answer (score 5):

This message is shown when loading a *har* archive. It means that the response body is not in the archive that you opened.

The body was not dropped by Fiddler. It was dropped by the creator of the .har file (eg Chrome).

See here: https://fiddler.ideas.aha.io/ideas/FID-I-40